# JS Nodes in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nodes

I am trying to add many options in a select tag.
My code is:

```
var years = document.getElementById("years");
for ( var i = 1526; i < 2013; i++) {
    var year = document.createElement("option");
    var text = document.createTextNode(i);
    year.appendChild(text);
    year.setAttribute("value", i);
    years.appendChild(year);
}
```

This doesn't work. There is something wrong with the appendChild function. The loop breaks after running once. I tried doing

```
var years = document.createElementNode("select");
```

but this also doesn't work. It runs but there is nothing on the webpage. No select tag and no options.

The Body:

```
<select id="years"></select>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML fragment around whatever element has `id='years'` too?

Comment: How did you figure the loop breaks after running once? http://jsfiddle.net/nwAFb/

Comment: You have a `getElementById("years")` ... for this to work, you need to have an actual HTML element with an ID of 'years', that looks something like the following: `<div id="years">`.  It's an important part of the data you're operating on, and it will help us if we can see it.

Comment: I tested it with document.write(). I commented it out and it wrote all years but when it was there it only wrote once if document.write() was before appendChild and if it was after appendChild, it didn't even write once.

Comment: Yes i have a select tag in the body with years id

Comment: I don't see `document.write` anywhere in your question. Why is that? Side note: `years.appendChild(new Option(i, i))` is nicer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know you have a select tag with ID years.  Can you paste the HTML in your question.  Please?

Answer (score 0):

I have used div tag in append child function

```
<html>
<script>
function loadOptions()
{
    var i;
    var selectdiv= "";
    selectdiv="<select>";
    for(i = 1526; i < 2013; i++){
        selectdiv+= "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
    }
        selectdiv+= "</select>";
    var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.innerHTML= selectdiv;
    document.getElementById('element1').appendChild(newDiv);
}
</script>
<body onload="loadOptions()">

<div id="element1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you